# Why does Room insert method not accept an Iterable?

Tags: android, collections, insert, android-room, iterable

I can compile the code:

```
@Update 
public abstract int update(Iterable<T> objects);
```

but when I try to compile

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
public abstract List<Long> insert(Iterable<T> objects);
```

there is a message from compiler:

```
error: no suitable method found for insertAndReturnIdsList(Iterable<SessionKey>)
method EntityInsertionAdapter.insertAndReturnIdsList(SessionKey[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Iterable<SessionKey> cannot be converted to SessionKey[])
method EntityInsertionAdapter.insertAndReturnIdsList(Collection<? extends SessionKey>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Iterable<SessionKey> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends SessionKey>)
```

As I have found `androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter`requires `Collection` as an argument:

```
List<Long> insertAndReturnIdsList(Collection<? extends T> entities)
```

and not an `Iterable`. **Why?**

Comment: Have you tried making the insert method void? Cause List<Long> is showing error.

Comment: Yes, `void insert(Iterable<T> objects)` doesn't produce an error on compiling, but why is such difference in interfaces for `update` and `insert` methods!?

Answer (score 1):

First, why you can not insert:
It 's about Java `Inheritance` and  `Polymorphism`
`Collection` is son of `Iterable`
you can pass `Collection` son class instance but not  `Iterable`

Secondry, why you can update 
In `EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter` source code is

```
public final int handleMultiple(Iterable<? extends T> entities) {
    final SupportSQLiteStatement stmt = acquire();
    try {
        int total = 0;
        for (T entity : entities) {
            bind(stmt, entity);
            total += stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
        }
        return total;
    } finally {
        release(stmt);
    }
}
```

parameter is `Iterable` not `Collection`

Comment: I understand your `First`, but don't understand whu `Room` disigners have made such difference between `insert` and `update` in the library. `Secondary`: I would like to use the `Room`-library code and write a bug report to developers if reasons for the narrowing of the acceptable argument class is absent.